# Spectral mixing model error in ImageCollection using Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I would like to create an ImageCollection, in specific months for the L5 with a filter that returns only one image per year, which can be the image with less cloud coverage, then apply a spectral linear mixing model and export all processed images to the google drive.
The problem occurs when I apply the function of the spectral linear mixture model to the distinct year collection I created. I believe the problem lies in this collection. I have no experience with GEE, could someone help me?

This is what I have so far:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b56794a03e7e4963ff226747c89518eb

```
var bacia = ee.FeatureCollection("users/geodenilson/Bacia_Carlos");
var roi = bacia.geometry();

// define custom function for exporting images to drive
var ExportCol = function(col, folder, scale, type,
                     nimg, maxPixels, region) {
type = type || "float";
nimg = nimg || 500;
scale = 30 || 1000;
maxPixels = maxPixels || 1e10;

var colList = col.toList(nimg);
var n = colList.size().getInfo();

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  var img = ee.Image(colList.get(i));
  var id = img.id().getInfo();
  region = roi || img.geometry().bounds().getInfo()["coordinates"];

  var imgtype = {"float":img.toFloat(),
                 "byte":img.toByte(),
                 "int":img.toInt(),
                 "double":img.toDouble()
                }

  Export.image.toDrive({
    image:imgtype[type],
    description: 'LANDSAT_5_'+id,
    folder: folder,
    //fileNamePrefix: id,
    region: region,
    scale: scale,
    maxPixels: maxPixels})
}}

var getFractionssn = function(ModeloMistura){
    // Define Endmembers
    var endmemberssn =[
            [150.0, 430.0, 270.0, 4300.0, 1500.0, 550.0], /*gv*/
            [1200.0, 2400.0, 3250.0, 4600.0, 5500.0, 3600.0], /*soil*/
            [160.0, 300.0, 170.0, 150.0, 50.0, 30.0] /*water*/
      ];
    // Uminxing Data
    var unmixedsn = (ModeloMistura)
                  .select('B1','B2','B3','B4','B5', 'B7')
                  .unmix(endmemberssn)
                  .max(0)
                  .multiply(100)
                  .byte();

  var detexsn = unmixedsn.expression(
    '120*(Soil/GV)+20', {
      'Soil': unmixedsn.select (1),
      'GV': unmixedsn.select (0)});

    return detexsn;
};

var lsCol = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(-44.85,-18.74))
  .filter(ee.Filter.dayOfYear(182, 243))
  // Add the observation year as a property to each image.
  .map(function(img) {
    return img.set('year', ee.Image(img).date().get('year'));
  });

// Make a distinct year collection; one image representative per year.
var distinctYears = lsCol.distinct('year').sort('year');

var result = distinctYears.map(getFractionssn)

ExportCol(result, 'GEE_output', 30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not so much wrong with the code. Just sometimes you will need to specifically cast an `ee.Feature` to an `ee.Image`. Not sure where and why this occasionally happens, maybe one of the GEE team can answer that question.

```
// Uminxing Data
var unmixedsn = ee.Image(ModeloMistura) // cast to an ee.Image
              .select('B1','B2','B3','B4','B5', 'B7')
              .unmix(endmemberssn)
              .max(0)
              .multiply(100)
              .byte();
```

[link full code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3542c43c55c21fd1468acbd23e5264c1)